# jQuery - checkbox data post to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I need help with this problem..

I have a form page that I'm checking with jQuery, then after inspection of the data is passed to the processing php.

Having problems with the checkboxes, radio buttons.

Somebody help me, how can I take them through the jQuery..?

I need full results, from start to finish.

The form: - I would like this data -

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="chk1" value="checkb1"/>Chk1
<input type="checkbox"  name="chk2" value="checkb2"/>Chk2

<input type="checkbox"  name="deliver[]" value="foreign"/>Foreign
<input type="checkbox"  name="deliver[]" value="internal"/>Internal

<input type="radio" name="button" value="button1" >Button1
<input type="radio" name="button" value="button2" >Button2
```

The jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){$('#submit').click(function()

{
var cim=$('input[name=cim]');
var name=$('input[name=name]');
var message=$('textarea[name=message]');

if(name.val()==''){alert("Pls fill out");name.addClass('hightlight');document.adatform.name.focus();return false;}else name.removeClass('hightlight');

var data='cim='+cim.val()
+'&name='+name.val()
+'&message='+encodeURIComponent(message.val());

$('.contact input, .contact textarea').attr('disabled','true');
$('.loading').show();$.ajax({url:"../contact-form/send.php",type:"POST",data:data,cache:false,success:function(result){if(result == 'sent'){$('.contact-form').hide(600);$('.form-success').fadeIn('slow');}else alert('error, try later');}
});return false;});});
```

Thank you

Comment: simply u just serialize the form then send to php file like var str = ('form').serialize(); data =  str and get php unserialize($_REQUEST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method

```
$.ajax({
    url:"../contact-form/send.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:$('form').serialize(),
    cache:false,
    success:function(result){
        if(result == 'sent'){$('.contact-form').hide(600);$('.form-success').fadeIn('slow');}else alert('error, try later');}
});
```

Comment: works! yesss! :)
thy-thy! :)